# How can I have an HTML element that behaves like an anchor, but is not an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

In short, I have a big box that I want users to be able to click on. 
When they click on it, it navigates to a certain URL. So... A link.

(This box does have a link inside with the corresponding HREF, but I want *the whole box* to be clickable)

For several reasons, having the actual anchor be as big as the box is really messy to my HTML layout, plus I have a bunch of blocks inside that box, etc, so I'm trying to find an alternative.

Right now, what I'm doing is:

```
$(box).click(function(){
  window.location.href = $(this).find("a.lnkWhatever").attr("href");
});
```

Which works... Kinda... But it's not quite a link, you can't Ctrl+Click it to open in a new tab, right clicking doesn't give you the nice options you get with a link, etc...

I *could* try and see if Ctrl happens to be pressed when they clicked, but I get the feeling I'm always going to have some abomination that works badly in some weird way or another...

Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing?

NOTE: I know I can style a link to be a big box, and normally I'd do that, but in this case, it's *really* problematic, I need to not do that

Thank you!
Daniel

Comment: Can you not wrap the `a` element around this "box"?

Comment: i'd wrap the box with the a tag. to be compliant html, you'll need to convert block level elements inside to inline level elements and set their style to display: block...

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm trying to avoid, for several reasons. Any other alternatives?

Comment: another option might be to set cursor:pointer; in the css for the box, and set the onclick event of the box to a bit of javascript that takes them to whatever page you want them to go to, although you won't get the right click menu w/out the a tag

Comment: why is it problematic to style it as a box? if you want an answer that isn't that you'll need to describe why you can't do that.

Comment: look like you are looking for custom tag inherited from anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

You could always just make the `a` element the box. Use css to display it block. [Here's a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/y9Qxa/).

Note: just clicking the demo does not load Google as the code would seem. JSFiddle does something weird here, but if you Ctrl + Click it it behaves as expected.

OR! (since you said there was an issue with doing it this way)

You you could capture the `click` and `contextmenu` events, figure out which event was triggered and change the action based on that. You could accomplish this with some code that looks like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/zKCZF/3/).

The JavaScript you would attach to the anchor would look like this:

```
$('a').on('click contextmenu', function (event) {
    if (event.type === 'contextmenu') {
        //execute what code you want
    }
    else {
        // this would automatically navigate to your link
        // so you could theoretically leave off the else portion
        // it just seemed like a nice place to leave this explanation
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If the box is relatively positioned, you can create an an absolute positioned anchor as the first element inside the div, and size it to 100%. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GQfVC/)

Edit - fixed link

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
        var a = $(this).find('a');
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            a.attr('target', '_blank');
        }
        a[0].click();
    });
})​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='mydiv'>
        hi world <br />
        <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>
        Hello <br />
        blah
    </div>​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6uHhu/)

However I am not sure if `.click()` is cross browser. You may need to take account different browsers

Comment: One of the reasons for jQuery is that it's abstracts a lot of the browser-specific stuff. So, yes click is cross-broser. There's no guarantee what mechanism it willactually use to attach the event though as _that_ is browser-specific

Comment: @Basic, the `click()` of jQuery is a function of `jQuery` object. I am using javascript object (See `a[0]`) . The jQuery's `click()` is not real click event. It simulates it and thus, it wont navigate you to other page.

Comment: I beg your pardon, I skimmed, saw the jQuery click and commented - you're quite right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

On inner anchor try to set:

```
display: block; 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Probably you may also need to set `position: relative;` on parent container

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n5536n1/2/)